# How to Create Multiple Modal Dynamically in a Single Page

Tags: javascript, html, django, bootstrap-modal

I am doing a Django Blog Project and it fetch all Blogs from the Database and show Blog Title in User Profile only. I want to create **Bootstrap Modal** for each Blog that is shown in the profile. Whenever a User click on a Title, the Modal will appear with Details.

```
{% for blog in blogs.all %}
  <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm ">
      <p class="card-text "><h2>{{ blog.title }}</h2></p>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="btn-group">

          <!-- Open a Modal for the blog -->
          <!-- Button To Implement the Modal-->
          <button id = "modalToggle" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">View More</button>

          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="modal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{ blog.title }}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <p>{{ blog.body }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Here all Blogs are showing the Modal of the first one. I cannot create **multiple modals for each Blog**.

Comment: Ah, worth noting when you are in the `for` loop & generating `modal`'s, you are generating (or at least attempting to), generate multiple `modal`'s with the same `id`. You can try to set the id to something incremental, which might be a good start / good practice

Comment: Please read more on `id` unique requirements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9454716/11700321)

Comment: I tried to increment the id but could not. I am very new in web development and Django. I could not figure it out how to use variable in html code and increment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` attribute of an html element should be unique and appear only on one element in the html document. The problem you're encountering is likely because you're creating an element with `id="modal"` for each blog. You can fix this with:

```
<button id = "modalToggle" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-blog-{{blog.pk}}">View More</button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="modal-blog-{{blog.pk}}" role="dialog">
```

By using a unique string for the id via including the blog pk the buttons should trigger their respective blog.

Comment: If I want to use a incremental variable in the loop and use it instead {{ blog.pk }} then how can I do that?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for Look towards the bottom of the `for` section. It describes some looping variables you can access.